# How to avoid a bloated index.html in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've started learning Angular last week and going through lots of tutorials and best practices. One of the tips that I often encountered was to separate each *controller*, *filter* and *service* into its own file.

The idea is great and there are lots of resources on how to do this, but nobody ever talks about the `index.html`. My problem is that every single one of those individual files will now have to be loaded through a separate `<script>` tag inside the `index.html`, which makes the file seem bloated. So I was wondering:

1. Will loading everything on app start affect the performance on a bigger Angular app with lots of controllers and 3rd party libraries?
2. Is using RequireJS necessary on bigger apps or will I just complicate things without getting the benefit of faster loading times? Or does Angular have a way of truly modularizing an app and have it load controllers / filters / services / 3rd party libs on demand?

So is this the way to go if I want to modularize my app? Should I just leave things as is and not worry about the performance?

Comment: It depends on the size of each controller, filter and service. Separate everything only if it is a big application, otherwise leave them together. It is not about performance, but clean code and understanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have dozens of files, all separated into controllers, directives, services and more, then simply use grunt or gulp to concatenate (and hopefully minify) them to one single file which you include. Take a look at [Grunt-contrib-concat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-concat) as an example grunt task.

Comment: I finally got my hands on a pretty big Angular project, which was pretty fast, even with all the script tags. After spending way too much time on it, I came to the same conclusion: concat and minify is the answer. Thanks!